# Can not use cuDNN on context None, fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, theano, cudnn, theano-cuda

I am trying to configure `theano` to use `gpu` on my windows machine. I have set up `.theanorc` to use `device= gpu` but when I run some code that should utilize the gpu, I get the following error:

```
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:
c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\try_flags_pt24sj.c:4:19: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Mapped name None to device cuda0: GeForce 840M (0000:03:00.0)
```

I have checked my `CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\v8.0` GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA to see whether cudnn.h is there or not, and I found it in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include`

Comment: I have the same problem. Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this with following the installation guide https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows and adding LIBRARY_PATH to the PATH variable (pointing to your CUDA lib folder e.g. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib).